# Liquibase + Postgresql + Spring Jpa : Id auto increment issue

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, liquibase

I have the following Id description in the entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Liquibase instruction for generate this id is following :

```
  <column name="id" autoIncrement="true"  type="INT">
     <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_entity"/>
  </column>
```

Also I have liquibase scripts that insert to this table predefined values, e.g.

```
    <insert tableName="entityTable" schemaName="public">
        <column name="id">1</column>    
        <!- other fields-->
    </insert>
```

The problem has appeared when I try to insert a new record without id using Jpa repository. 
I got an error with a message like "duplicate id".
So, I understand that jpa(hibernate) doesn't use postgresql sequence for getting a new id value. And I don't want to include the sequence name to the entity's id description. I have hoped that this situation could be resolved by the postgresql itself. 
And I wouldn't to use the 'hibernate_sequence'.
So, any idea how I can resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI JPA `GenerationType.IDENTITY` for PostgreSQL will mean use "SERIAL" column type (i.e generated in the datastore). This is not a SEQUENCE. If you wanted a SEQUENCE then you would have used JPA `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: I know, but the liquibase doesn't generate 'serial' type.

Comment: so you cant use IDENTITY with JPA if you want to use both JPA and Liquibase ...

Comment: If you use `autoIncrement="true"` then Liquibase **will** generate a `serial` column

Answer (score 12):

Liquibase's instruction `autoIncrement="true"` generates `serial` column for PostgreSQL. For `serial` column PostgreSQL will create a sequence with a name like `tablename_colname_seq`. Default column values will be assigned from this sequence.

But when you *explicitly* insert a value into serial column, it doesn't affect sequence generator, and its next value will not change. So it can generate a duplicate value, which is exactly your case.

To prevent this after you inserted explicit values you need to change the current value of a sequence generator either with `ALTER SEQUENCE` statement or with `setval()` function, e.g.:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq RESTART WITH 42;

SELECT setval('tablename_colname_seq', (SELECT max(colname) FROM tablename));
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: I do not think that it is a good idea to manually update the sequence in a multithreaded application.

Answer (score 0):

First create to table name example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(ID_NAME SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);
```

Then in your annotation:

```java
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long nameAtribute;
```