# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_jhi_persistent_audit_event" with JHipster on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, heroku, jhipster

I recently [upgraded a JHipster 2.x application to 4.x](http://www.jhipster-book.com/#!/news/entry/upgrading-21-points-health-from-v1-to-v4) as part of writing the JHipster Mini-Book's sample application. Lately, I've been experiencing quite a few issues with login and registration. It seems to be caused by the sequence keys in some of the auditing tables:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_jhi_persistent_audit_event"
```

Full log:

```
2017-12-19T02:44:25.564551+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-12-19 02:44:25.564  WARN 4 --- [ XNIO-2 task-26] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
2017-12-19T02:44:25.564734+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-12-19 02:44:25.564 ERROR 4 --- [ XNIO-2 task-26] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_jhi_persistent_audit_event"
2017-12-19T02:44:25.564737+00:00 app[web.1]:   Detail: Key (event_id)=(42094) already exists.
2017-12-19T02:44:25.565215+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-12-19 02:44:25.565 ERROR 4 --- [ XNIO-2 task-26] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
2017-12-19T02:44:25.567741+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017-12-19 02:44:25.567 ERROR 4 --- [ XNIO-2 task-26] o.j.h.w.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator  : An unexpected error occurred: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [pk_jhi_persistent_audit_event]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2017-12-19T02:44:27.820781+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=523M(102.1%)
2017-12-19T02:44:27.820897+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-12-19T02:44:25.571359+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/authenticate" host=www.21-points.com request_id=b54f7527-7479-42ee-acaa-d6794567c118 fwd="75.171.150.21" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=156ms status=500 bytes=550 protocol=https
```

Is it possible to reset the sequences for these tables, or move to a guid-based system that won't have collisions? I'm using PostgreSQL on Heroku.

Comment: To workaround the issue, I delete the data in the `jhi_persistent_*` auditing-related tables. It typically starts happening again in a few days though.

Comment: have you found workaround or solution for this yet?

Comment: No, but I may switch to using UUID's as recommended by Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-production-on-heroku#use-uuids-for-all-postgres-primary-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround I adopted was to set a **rollbackFor=Exception.class** in my **CustomAuditEventRepository**

It catch the exception and just rollback the transaction: so the login audit event will not be saved, but at least you are not going to have annoying exceptions that lock the app.

```
 @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public void add(AuditEvent event) {
        if (!AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE.equals(event.getType()) &&
            !Constants.ANONYMOUS_USER.equals(event.getPrincipal())) {
                PersistentAuditEvent persistentAuditEvent = new PersistentAuditEvent();
                persistentAuditEvent.setPrincipal(event.getPrincipal());
                persistentAuditEvent.setAuditEventType(event.getType());
                persistentAuditEvent.setAuditEventDate(event.getTimestamp());
                Map<String, String> eventData = auditEventConverter.convertDataToStrings(event.getData());
                persistentAuditEvent.setData(truncate(eventData));
                persistenceAuditEventRepository.save(persistentAuditEvent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Nadir - I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried this in my app and deployed a new version today. Unfortunately, the problem still happens.

Comment: @MattRaible, I suggest in your case to skip the save cmd commenting out persistenceAuditEventRepository.save(persistentAuditEvent);

This will not log connection info data in that table, but at least your users will not encounter login problems.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem also with a 5.8.2 Jhipster microservice application (gateway + microservice) based on Postgres db. Especially after rebuilding the ms, I got the notorious:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_jhi_persistent_audit_event"

I have observed that, when it happened, there was an overlapping of keys for hibernate_sequence as its next value retrieved with pgAdmin was different by the key that the application was trying to write in the audit table (curiously there was a difference of 50 or less...). I don't know in which way Hibernate deals with sequenceGenerator but this post gives me some tips (the fourth answer):

[Liquibase + Postgresql + Spring Jpa : Id auto increment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744365/liquibase-postgresql-spring-jpa-id-auto-increment-issue)

I have not in my Postgres db a serial datatype for the id column, but indeed the behaviour is similar - Hibernate seems to send key values taken from some cache that survive also after a rebuilding. So I give up with Hibernate sequence and I created a new ordinary postgres sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.id_persistent_audit_event_seq
    AS bigint    
    MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE
    START WITH 1
    CACHE 50;
```

On Java side (PersistentAuditEvent.java):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "audit_event_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "audit_event_generator", sequenceName="id_persistent_audit_event_seq", allocationSize=1)
@Column(name = "event_id")
private Long id;
```

Note the `allocationSize=1` but `CACHE 50` in Postgres. This should avoid performance issues on database side (look at jdubois' comment of 14 Sep 2018 in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/8029).

Hope it helps, now everything is working well for me!